# Podcasting with a RoR Base and Heroku Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, itunes, podcast

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for building a site in RoR for podcasting. I'm just looking to build a simple blog with uploadable podcasts. I can do all of this no problem and I plan to send all of the podcasts up to S3 and mirror to CloudFront. (This would lower my costs and allow me to deploy to Heroku)

My main question is how should I go about generating my iTunes feed from a table of titles, descriptions, and CloudFront links so that I can use iTunes for distribution without having to outsource to something like Feedburner or Podbean?

Any suggestions or comments are always welcome! Thanks :)

-Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the format.xml method in your controller (on the index method), so that you have that as an output format.

Actually forming the podcast format you want for the xml is a little more difficult. I would follow something similar to what is set up here:

http://danengle.us/2009/05/generating-custom-xml-for-your-rails-app/